# find an element in a list with 'in' keyword and return that element

Tags: python, arrays

using the 'in' keyword i can find if an element is in an array:

```
a=[1,2,3]
if 1 in a:
    print "1 present in a"
```

is there a way to return the index of where 'in' found that element?

Comment: That's not really a 3d array. That's a 1d array with 3 elements.

Comment: @Falmarri is right- do you mean a list with 3 elements?

Comment: No I didn't mean a list with 3 elements. I was going to ask a question about 3d lists but I suppose I decided while writing the question that what I could learn about 1d lists could easily be applied to 3d lists. I fixed the title in an edit there, and changed the word array to the standard python terminology (list, not array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1-d list:**

```
  a=[1,2,3]
    def indd(val):
     try:   
       ind=a.index(val)
       return ind,val
     except:
       return 'not found'  

    print(indd(1))  
    print(indd(5))   

    (0,1)
    not found
```

**for a 3-d list the function function will return a tuple of the x,y,z , if the number is repeated inside the 3d list then it'll return the lowest index :**

```
def ind_3d(lis,val):
    ind=[(j,i,k) for j,x in enumerate(lis) for i,y in enumerate(x) for k,z in enumerate(y) if z==val]
    if len(ind)==0:
        return 'not found'
    else:
        return ind[0]

a=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]]]

print(ind_3d(a,11))
print(ind_3d(a,5))
print(ind_3d(a,25))
```

**output:**

```
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `a.index(1)` to get the position of `1` in the list if you know it exists for sure. Otherwise use a try/catch block.

Also, they're called "lists" in Python :) The more accurate you are with terminology the easier it is to keep track later of how they're implemented and what functions they support.

**EDIT**: For a multi-dimensional list (i.e. list of lists in case of 2-D), you'll have to iterate over the top `n-1` levels, where `n` is the dimensionality. For 2-D, assuming you're searching for `1`, something like this will work:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    if 1 in val:
        return idx, val.index(1)
```

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit and take the 3d bit out :p